# Make a TextView visible in a ListView row only on one line via adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-view, simplecursoradapter, listadapter

I wanna highlight only one row at the time, I'am doing this by making a `TextView` visible (or use the BadgeView library, which I used in my first try but produced this bug and I thought it was a flaw / bug of the library).

**This is my approach:** (I have overriden this method in my `SimpleCursorAdapter`)

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

    int rowId = Integer.valueOf(((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.two_line_rowid)).getText().toString());

    if (rowId == mRowIdSelected) {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText("SELECTED");
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.select_badge)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

It works pretty well, but there is a bug. The text in the `android.R.id.text1` only change in the selected row, this is working as intended, but the `TextView` is made visible in the first row **and** the selected row, which is not working as intended.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

    int rowId = Integer.valueOf(((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.two_line_rowid)).getText().toString());

    if (rowId == mRowIdSelected) {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText("SELECTED");
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.select_badge)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText("NOT-SELECTED");
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.select_badge)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Can you provide the layout of the view that your passing?

Comment: Hell yeah, works. Thanks a lot. I don't know why I don't had this idea. ;)

Comment: Nice :) then i dont need the layout.